# Short exact sequences of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

If we have the following  exact sequences of $R-$modules

$0 \rightarrow M_1 \stackrel{f} \rightarrow N \stackrel{g} \rightarrow L_1 \rightarrow 0$

$0 \rightarrow M_2 \stackrel{h} \rightarrow N \stackrel{k} \rightarrow L_2 \rightarrow 0$

and we know that $k \circ f$ is a R-isomorphism

> How can we show that  $g \circ h$ is also a R-isomorphism?

Comment: Just play with your sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I just played with your sequences and here is my partial solution.

We need to show two things. First, that $\ker(g\circ h)=\{0\}$ and second, that $g\circ h$ is surjective.

To show that $\ker(g\circ h)=\{0\}$ we chose an element $x\in \ker(g\circ h)$, so $(g\circ h)(x)=g(h(x))=0$, this means that $h(x)\in \ker(g)=\text{Im}(f)$, so there is some $y\in M_1$ such that $h(x)=f(y)$. Applying $k$ to both sides we get $k(h(x))=k(f(y))$, but $h(x)\in \text{Im}(h)=\ker(k)$, thus $k(f(y))=k(h(x))=0$. By hypothesis $k\circ f$ is iso, hence $y=0$ and this gives us that $h(x)=f(y)=f(0)=0$. Since $h$ is injective, we conclude that $x=0$, as desired.

To show that $g\circ h$ is surjective, you have to use your hypothesis and "play" like I did to prove that $\ker(g\circ h)=\{0\}$.

Comment: If you need help to show that $g\circ h$ is surjective I can edit to complete the answer.

Comment: To show that $g \circ h$ is surjective i started this way: Taking a non-zero element $x \in L_1$, since $g$ is surjective we have $n \in N$ such that $g(n)=x$. I am trying to show that $k(n)=0$, to conclude that $n \in Ker(k)=Im(h)$ but i am stucked in that part...(I'm not used to writing in English)

Comment: Your initial idea is right. Now, since $n\in N$, then $k(n)\in L_2$, so from $k\circ f$ being iso we deduce that there is $y\in M_1$ such that $k(f(y))=k(n)$, so $k(n-f(y)))=0$, i.e., $n-f(y)\in \ker(k)=\text{Im}(h)$. Hence there is $z\in M_2$ such that $h(z)=n-f(y)$. From here I think you can conclude.